# Windows Image Acquisition Fail

Tags: vb.net, wia

I try to acquire image from scanner using the code below

```
Dim CD As New WIA.CommonDialog
Dim F As WIA.ImageFile = CD.ShowAcquireImage(WIA.WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType)
F.SaveFile("C:\Temp\WIA\" + F.FileExtension)
```

But it produce me this error:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Test.exe
>
> Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a
>   call to a COM component.

Help help.

Comment: *sidenote:* vb.net , vba and vb6 are 3 sets of programming languages.

Comment: ok changed. Should be vb.net. Help me! plz

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the scanner you want to use :

```
    Dim DeviceID As String
    Dim class1 As CommonDialogClass = New CommonDialogClass
    Dim d As Device = class1.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, True, False)
    If (Not (d) Is Nothing) Then
        DeviceID = d.DeviceID
    End If
```

then you take the picture :

```
    Dim manager As DeviceManager = New DeviceManagerClass
    Dim d1 As Device = Nothing
    For Each info As DeviceInfo In manager.DeviceInfos
        If (info.DeviceID = DeviceID) Then
            d1 = info.Connect
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Dim item As Item = d1.Items(1)
    Dim imagefile As WIA.ImageFile = CType(item.Transfer(), WIA.ImageFile)
    imagefile.SaveFile("D:\IMg1.jpg")
```

Hope this help.

Refer to this Link From More Info [Windows Image Acquisition](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/Look-at-me-Windows-Image-Acquisition)

**Edit**
Add reference to your project `wiaaut.dll` you can find  it on `C:\Windows\system32`.
And `Imports WIA` to your class.

Comment: does scanner works and Windows 8 work too? Because previously i used Twain and it work very well in Windows 7 but not in Windows 8

Comment: Interop type 'CommonDialogClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead. 

Interop type 'DeviceManagerClass' cannot be embedded. Use the applicable interface instead.

What can i do about it? Ty (:

Comment: did you add wiaaut.dll to your project?? check my answer.

Comment: Yup. I referenced Microsoft Windows Image Acquisition Library v2.0 into the project file.And I make some change from"Dim class1 As CommonDialogClass = New CommonDialogClass"to "Dim class1 As CommonDialog = New CommonDialog"and "Dim manager As DeviceManager = New DeviceManagerClass"to "Dim manager As DeviceManager = New DeviceManager".Error are eliminated but when run, error message like "An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in WindowsApplication1.exe
Additional information: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."

Comment: what is your windows version? and whet IDE you use?

Comment: Windows 8.1 64 bit. Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013. Sincerely, I already had one complete solution but it's only working in Windows 7 not Windows 8.1. And my company can't use Windows 7 as we can't downgrade and we want to stay genuine... Maybe any other solution(I know JAVA and Php only, still studying my skipped 2nd year).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44705/discussion-between-user2454048-and-al-3sli)